# Optimizing a while loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop

I have a while loop, where I did this

```
let count = 0,
  amount = 1000,
  arrayOfAmounts = [0];

while (count < amount) {
  count += 1000;
  if (count <= amount) {
    arrayOfAmounts.push(count);
    console.log(count);
  }
}
```

When the value in the amount variable gets large it slows down the process, for example, say I have 50000000, it sometimes either crash my browser or gets really slow. I know why this happens, but I would really love to know how to optimize this code so its a bit faster than it is.

**What I am trying to solve:**
So I'm trying to generate an array of numbers in their thousands based on what value is in the variable amount. For example, say, the variable amount is 5000, I want to generate an array with values 0, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: keep in mind console.log slows down execution a lot

Comment: So I'm trying to generate an array of numbers in their thousands based on what value is in the variable `amount`. For example, say, the variable amount is 5000, i want to generate an array with values 0, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000

Comment: I don't really see a reason to add those values to an array. Instead of getting the value by  `arrayOfAmounts[index]`, you can simply calculate it with `index * 1000`.

Comment: yeah, you are right @HarisBouchlis I only added it to see how things were, without the log it was still slow

Comment: You should consider using `setInterval`. Since it's asynchronous, it won't crash your Browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get an array like this, simply use Array.from

```js
const additionPerLoop = 1000;
const amount = 10000;
const res = Array.from({length: Math.floor(amount / additionPerLoop) + 1}, (_, i) => i * additionPerLoop);

console.log(res);
```